# XML for tv listing

Tags: xsd

i have the webage tvguide  [tvguide](http://www.tvguide.com/Listings/)and i am having problem on how to start coding the xml for it just sample data
 i can omit the advertising elements 
XML Language should consist of:
    a. XML Sample Data
    b. DTD to define the sample data
    c. Either an XML XSLT or and XSL-FO
    d. CSS if you select XSLT

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear:

1. For generating xml from xsd you can use online tools like: http://xmlgrid.net/genXml.html
2. You can also use Eclipse, or any other IDE.
3. Why do you need DTD? XSD is like DTD only better.
4. XSLT helps transforming one XML to another, why do you need it?
5. How is CSS related?

Comment: from the webpage i provided i should create a sample data xml file for the tv listing and after that i will create a DTD for it and an XSLT to transformet to HTML and i will use CSS to Style it